# How to trigger a capture using Picamera when a particular event occurs (for eg, whenever a specific object appears in front of the camera)

Tags: python, camera, video, picamera

I want to trigger an image capture every time a tyre of a set of moving vehicles appears just in front of the picamera. Is there any way to get this done automatically every time a tyre appears in front of the camera ?

Comment: There's like a zillion possibility to do that, you need to ask a more specific question. 

Do you want to recognize tire ? If so you can train a model to recognize just that.

Is the camera fixed on something and the background picture remain the same ? Then you should probably try to detect edges and movement. ....

Answer (score 1):

Example from [here](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html) :

```
import picamera
import picamera.array
import numpy as np

class MyMotionDetector(picamera.array.PiMotionAnalysis):
    def analyse(self, a):
        a = np.sqrt(
            np.square(a['x'].astype(np.float)) +
            np.square(a['y'].astype(np.float))
            ).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
        # If there're more than 10 vectors with a magnitude greater
        # than 60, then say we've detected motion
        if (a > 60).sum() > 10:
            print('Motion detected!')

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 30
    camera.start_recording(
        '/dev/null', format='h264',
        motion_output=MyMotionDetector(camera)
        )
    camera.wait_recording(30)
    camera.stop_recording()
```

New in version 1.5.